# Create global variable in jQuery outside document.ready function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a function CreateTable and generate constant variable .I want to access the variable in other function.Which I click the button it call the function generatePDF.There I want to check the length of the dummy value which is generated inside generteTable function.
now getting the error message 'Uncaught ReferenceError: dummy is not defined'

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
generateTable();

function generateTable() {
  const dummy = [{
    "key": "value",
    "key1": "value1"
  }]; //created by some other fnction;
}
   }
function generatePDF() {
  if (dummy.length) {
    //do sone thing
    alert('hello');
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="generatePDF()">Make PDF</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a `global` var outside the document ready function it will become available one the `DOM` is ready.

Run snippet below.

```js
//Global Var
let dummy;

//Document ready start here
$(document).ready(function() {
  function generateTable() {
    dummy = [{
      "key": "value",
      "key1": "value1"
    }]; //created by some other fnction;
  }
  generateTable();
});


//Outside document ready
function generatePDF() {
  if (dummy.length) {
    //do sone thing
    alert('hello');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="generatePDF()">Make PDF</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because the variable "dummy" is not a global variable.
It is a local variable in the function generateTable.

```js
let dummy;

generateTable();
function generateTable() {
  dummy = [{ key: "value", key1: "value1" }]; //created by some other fnction;
}

function generatePDF() {
  if (dummy.length) {
    //do sone thing
    alert("hello");
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="generatePDF()">Make PDF</button>
```

here turn the dummy into global variable

Comment: generateTable in document.ready function.So getting generatePdf in not defined.Please check my updated post

Answer (score 0):

First declare the variable outside of the function as;

```
const dummy;
```

and then write other code.Now it becomes available globally.

Comment: and in the function don't add "const" in front of the variable after declaring it outside.

Comment: You can't/shouldn't override `const` declarations; Also, discourage the use of global variables.

Comment: I mean just declare it then set the value where u need.

Answer (score 0):

The dummy value can only be used in this function generateTable.if you want to use dummy,you should define a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var x;
    x=generateTable();
    
    function generateTable() {
      const dummy = [{
        "key": "value",
        "key1": "value1"
      }]; //created by some other fnction;
    return(dummy);
    }

   }
function generatePDF() {
  if (x.length) {
    //do sone thing
    alert('hello');
  }
}
```